How to use CMake with offloading-enabled gcc built from source
I want to use an offloading-enabled gcc in a CMake project.
To this end, I built gcc from source to use it for OpenMP offloading to an NVIDIA GPU. I could not use distro packages, because of recent CUDA versions not supporting sm_30 (see here).
After some trial and error, gcc itself works now. For anyone interested, here's what I did:
#!/bin/bash

set -euv

# build offloading-enabled gcc from source. Used references:
# https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading
# https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#nvptx-x-none

INSTDIR=$HOME/pkg/omp-gcc
WORKDIR=$INSTDIR/src
nproc=16

mkdir -p $WORKDIR && cd $WORKDIR

# nvptx-tools first, which we'll need before building gcc
git clone https://github.com/SourceryTools/nvptx-tools

# now let's get gcc. To make it reproducible, let's grab an actual release.
# downloading takes a minute
wget https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/releases/gcc-13.2.0/gcc-13.2.0.tar.xz

# We also need Newlib. That's why the error "C compiler cannot create executables"
# occurred before.
# this says so: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Offloading, under Building and obtaining GCC
NEWLIBVER=newlib-4.4.0.20231231
# Alternatively, you could use git clone, but that's much slower
wget ftp://sourceware.org/pub/newlib/$NEWLIBVER.tar.gz

# extract archives
tar -xf gcc-13.2.0.tar.xz
tar -xzf $NEWLIBVER.tar.gz

cd $WORKDIR/gcc-13.2.0
# download further dependencies
./contrib/download_prerequisites

# let Newlib be built together with gcc, otherwise you get the error: C compiler cannot create executables
ln -s $WORKDIR/$NEWLIBVER/newlib .

# now we do the compilations.
cd $WORKDIR/nvptx-tools
# this takes a little bit
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=$INSTDIR/nvptx-tools
# but the actual compilation is fast
make -j$nproc && make install

# we need to create two builds, one for the host, one for the device.
# first, the GPU build
cd $WORKDIR/gcc-13.2.0
mkdir build-nv && cd build-nv

../configure --prefix=$INSTDIR/gcc-13.2.0 \
    --with-build-time-tools=$INSTDIR/nvptx-tools/nvptx-none/bin \
    --target=nvptx-none --with-arch=sm_70 \
    --enable-as-accelerator-for=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

# then, the host build
cd $WORKDIR/gcc-13.2.0
mkdir build-gcc && cd build-gcc

../configure --prefix=$INSTDIR/gcc-13.2.0 --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --disable-multilib

cd ../build-nv
make -j$nproc && make install

cd ../build-gcc
make -j$nproc && make install

for bin in ar as ld nm ranlib; do
    ln -s \
        $INSTDIR/nvptx-tools/bin/nvptx-none-$bin \
        $INSTDIR/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/accel/nvptx-none/$bin
done

echo "Now you can call $INSTDIR/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc"
$INSTDIR/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc --version

echo "You may delete the contents of $WORKDIR now with"
echo "rm -rf $WORKDIR"

Here's my code file to test whether everything's working (just C, but the overall project is C++):
#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#else
#error "OpenMP support required"
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(){
    const int size = 1 << 16;

    // Platform information
    printf("OpenMP version (yyyymm): %i\n", _OPENMP);
    printf("Number of OpenMP devices: %i\n", omp_get_num_devices());

    printf("* Allocate memory on the host\n");
    double *a = (double *) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    if (a == NULL) {
        errx(1, "malloc a[] failed");
    }

    printf("* Preprocess / initialize data on the host\n");
    printf("  e.g. read data from storage\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = 0.;
    }

    printf("* Copy data from the host to the device\n");
    #pragma omp target enter data map(to: a[0:size])
    {}

    printf("* Compute on the device\n");
    // #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for simd
    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i]++;
    }

    printf("* Transfer data back from the device to the host\n");
    #pragma omp target update from(a[0:size])
    {}

    printf("* Delete data on the device");
    #pragma omp target exit data map(release: a[0:size])
    {}

    printf("* Postprocess data on the host\n");
    printf("  e.g. write data to storage\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] != 1.) {
            errx(2, "Computation on GPU failed");
        }
    }

    printf("* Free memory on the host\n");
    free(a);

    return 0;
}

This code file (omp_offloading.cpp) can be compiled with a simple command:
~/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/g++ omp_offloading.cpp -o build/omp_offloading_gcc -fopenmp

However, I can't get it to work with CMake. Here's my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20 FATAL_ERROR)

project("omp-offload-gcc")

message(STATUS "Using CXX compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")

message( STATUS "Checking OpenMP")
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Checking OpenMP - found version " ${OpenMP_CXX_VERSION})
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Checking OpenMP - not found" )
endif()

add_executable( print omp_offloading.cpp )

target_link_libraries( print PRIVATE
    OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX
)

My configure command works:
cmake -B build-cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$HOME/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$HOME/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/g++

However, the compilation fails.
cmake --build build-cmake

The output is:
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/print.dir/omp_offloading.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable print
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc266KbP.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x0): undefined reference to `__offload_func_table'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc266KbP.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x8): undefined reference to `__offload_funcs_end'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc266KbP.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x10): undefined reference to `__offload_var_table'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc266KbP.crtoffloadtable.o:(.rodata+0x18): undefined reference to `__offload_vars_end'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/print.dir/build.make:99: print] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/print.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

I thought this looks like CMake using the wrong linker or something like that. I tried adding $HOME/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/accel/nvptx-none to PATH, but that resulted in CMake telling me that my C compiler is broken:
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc - broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: '/home/me/trash-tryouts/omp_offload_gcc/build-cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JXJCJQ'
    
    Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/cmake -E env VERBOSE=1 /usr/bin/gmake -f Makefile cmTC_35992/fast
    /usr/bin/gmake  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/me/trash-tryouts/omp_offload_gcc/build-cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JXJCJQ'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/bin/gcc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /home/me/trash-tryouts/omp_offload_gcc/build-cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JXJCJQ/testCCompiler.c
    as: unrecognized option '--64'
    Usage: nvptx-none-as [option...] [asmfile]
    Options:
      -m TARGET             Override target architecture used for ptxas
                            verification (default: deduce from input's preamble)
      -o FILE               Write output to FILE
      -v                    Be verbose
      --verify              Do verify output is acceptable to ptxas
      --no-verify           Do not verify output is acceptable to ptxas
      --help                Print this help and exit
      --version             Print version number and exit
    
    Report bugs to <https://github.com/MentorEmbedded/nvptx-tools/issues>.
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/build.make:78: CMakeFiles/cmTC_35992.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/me/trash-tryouts/omp_offload_gcc/build-cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-JXJCJQ'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:127: cmTC_35992/fast] Error 2

Here's the output of the compilation with gcc, using -Wl,-verbose:
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep
   i386pe
using internal linker script:
==================================================
/* Script for -z combreloc -z separate-code */
/* Copyright (C) 2014-2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   Copying and distribution of this script, with or without modification,
   are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
   notice and this notice are preserved.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf64-x86-64", "elf64-x86-64",
              "elf64-x86-64")
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386:x86-64)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
SECTIONS
{
  PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
  .interp         : { *(.interp) }
  .note.gnu.build-id  : { *(.note.gnu.build-id) }
  .hash           : { *(.hash) }
  .gnu.hash       : { *(.gnu.hash) }
  .dynsym         : { *(.dynsym) }
  .dynstr         : { *(.dynstr) }
  .gnu.version    : { *(.gnu.version) }
  .gnu.version_d  : { *(.gnu.version_d) }
  .gnu.version_r  : { *(.gnu.version_r) }
  .rela.dyn       :
    {
      *(.rela.init)
      *(.rela.text .rela.text.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.t.*)
      *(.rela.fini)
      *(.rela.rodata .rela.rodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.r.*)
      *(.rela.data .rela.data.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.d.*)
      *(.rela.tdata .rela.tdata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.td.*)
      *(.rela.tbss .rela.tbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.tb.*)
      *(.rela.ctors)
      *(.rela.dtors)
      *(.rela.got)
      *(.rela.bss .rela.bss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.b.*)
      *(.rela.ldata .rela.ldata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.l.*)
      *(.rela.lbss .rela.lbss.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
      *(.rela.lrodata .rela.lrodata.* .rela.gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
      *(.rela.ifunc)
    }
  .rela.plt       :
    {
      *(.rela.plt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_start = .);
      *(.rela.iplt)
      PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__rela_iplt_end = .);
    }
  .relr.dyn : { *(.relr.dyn) }
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  .init           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.init)))
  }
  .plt            : { *(.plt) *(.iplt) }
.plt.got        : { *(.plt.got) }
.plt.sec        : { *(.plt.sec) }
  .text           :
  {
    *(.text.unlikely .text.*_unlikely .text.unlikely.*)
    *(.text.exit .text.exit.*)
    *(.text.startup .text.startup.*)
    *(.text.hot .text.hot.*)
    *(SORT(.text.sorted.*))
    *(.text .stub .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)
    /* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf.em.  */
    *(.gnu.warning)
  }
  .fini           :
  {
    KEEP (*(SORT_NONE(.fini)))
  }
  PROVIDE (__etext = .);
  PROVIDE (_etext = .);
  PROVIDE (etext = .);
  . = ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE));
  /* Adjust the address for the rodata segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = SEGMENT_START("rodata-segment", ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)));
  .rodata         : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r.*) }
  .rodata1        : { *(.rodata1) }
  .eh_frame_hdr   : { *(.eh_frame_hdr) *(.eh_frame_entry .eh_frame_entry.*) }
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RO { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .gnu_extab   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.gnu_extab*) }
  /* These sections are generated by the Sun/Oracle C++ compiler.  */
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RO { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
     the same address within the page on the next page up.  */
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE), CONSTANT (COMMONPAGESIZE));
  /* Exception handling  */
  .eh_frame       : ONLY_IF_RW { KEEP (*(.eh_frame)) *(.eh_frame.*) }
  .gnu_extab      : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gnu_extab) }
  .gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
  .exception_ranges   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.exception_ranges*) }
  /* Thread Local Storage sections  */
  .tdata          :
   {
     PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__tdata_start = .);
     *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*)
   }
  .tbss           : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
  .preinit_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  }
  .init_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.init_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  }
  .fini_array    :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.fini_array.*) SORT_BY_INIT_PRIORITY(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtbegin.o *crtbegin?.o *crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  }
  .ctors          :
  {
    /* gcc uses crtbegin.o to find the start of
       the constructors, so we make sure it is
       first.  Because this is a wildcard, it
       doesn't matter if the user does not
       actually link against crtbegin.o; the
       linker won't look for a file to match a
       wildcard.  The wildcard also means that it
       doesn't matter which directory crtbegin.o
       is in.  */
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.ctors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.ctors))
    /* We don't want to include the .ctor section from
       the crtend.o file until after the sorted ctors.
       The .ctor section from the crtend file contains the
       end of ctors marker and it must be last */
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .ctors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.ctors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.ctors))
  }
  .dtors          :
  {
    KEEP (*crtbegin.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*crtbegin?.o(.dtors))
    KEEP (*(EXCLUDE_FILE (*crtend.o *crtend?.o ) .dtors))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.dtors.*)))
    KEEP (*(.dtors))
  }
  .jcr            : { KEEP (*(.jcr)) }
  .data.rel.ro : { *(.data.rel.ro.local* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.local.*) *(.data.rel.ro .data.rel.ro.* .gnu.linkonce.d.rel.ro.*) }
  .dynamic        : { *(.dynamic) }
  .got            : { *(.got) *(.igot) }
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END (SIZEOF (.got.plt) >= 24 ? 24 : 0, .);
  .got.plt        : { *(.got.plt) *(.igot.plt) }
  .data           :
  {
    *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d.*)
    SORT(CONSTRUCTORS)
  }
  .data1          : { *(.data1) }
  _edata = .; PROVIDE (edata = .);
  . = .;
  __bss_start = .;
  .bss            :
  {
   *(.dynbss)
   *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
   *(COMMON)
   /* Align here to ensure that the .bss section occupies space up to
      _end.  Align after .bss to ensure correct alignment even if the
      .bss section disappears because there are no input sections.
      FIXME: Why do we need it? When there is no .bss section, we do not
      pad the .data section.  */
   . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  .lbss   :
  {
    *(.dynlbss)
    *(.lbss .lbss.* .gnu.linkonce.lb.*)
    *(LARGE_COMMON)
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  . = SEGMENT_START("ldata-segment", .);
  .lrodata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.lrodata .lrodata.* .gnu.linkonce.lr.*)
  }
  .ldata   ALIGN(CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE)) + (. & (CONSTANT (MAXPAGESIZE) - 1)) :
  {
    *(.ldata .ldata.* .gnu.linkonce.l.*)
    . = ALIGN(. != 0 ? 64 / 8 : 1);
  }
  . = ALIGN(64 / 8);
  _end = .; PROVIDE (end = .);
  . = DATA_SEGMENT_END (.);
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab          0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr       0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl     0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr  0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index    0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment       0 : { *(.comment) }
  .gnu.build.attributes : { *(.gnu.build.attributes .gnu.build.attributes.*) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1.  */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions.  */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2.  */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line .debug_line.* .debug_line_end) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
  /* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions.  */
  .debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
  .debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
  .debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
  .debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
  /* DWARF 3.  */
  .debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
  .debug_ranges   0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }
  /* DWARF 5.  */
  .debug_addr     0 : { *(.debug_addr) }
  .debug_line_str 0 : { *(.debug_line_str) }
  .debug_loclists 0 : { *(.debug_loclists) }
  .debug_macro    0 : { *(.debug_macro) }
  .debug_names    0 : { *(.debug_names) }
  .debug_rnglists 0 : { *(.debug_rnglists) }
  .debug_str_offsets 0 : { *(.debug_str_offsets) }
  .debug_sup      0 : { *(.debug_sup) }
  .gnu.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
  /DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) *(.gnu.lto_*) }
}


==================================================
/usr/bin/ld: mode elf_x86_64
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtbegin.o succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtbegin.o
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtoffloadbegin.o succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtoffloadbegin.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccFvbtFH.o succeeded
/tmp/ccFvbtFH.o
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgomp.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgomp.a failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgomp.so succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgomp.so
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libc.a failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libc.a failed
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so succeeded
opened script file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
opened script file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
attempt to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a succeeded
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
attempt to open /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 succeeded
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc_s.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc_s.a failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so succeeded
opened script file /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
opened script file /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/libgcc.a
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtend.o succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtend.o
attempt to open /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o succeeded
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
attempt to open /home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtoffloadend.o succeeded
/home/me/pkg/omp-gcc/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/13.2.0/crtoffloadend.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccIQEaTC.crtoffloadtable.o succeeded
/tmp/ccIQEaTC.crtoffloadtable.o
attempt to open /tmp/ccwYxOGB.target.o succeeded
/tmp/ccwYxOGB.target.o
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 needed by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
found ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

How can I get CMake to work with my offloading-enabled gcc?

"I thought this looks like CMake using the wrong linker or something like that." - Usually CMake just calls the compiler for perform linking step. You could easy check that by using make VERBOSE=1. If the compiler calls wrong linker, then it is problem of the your compiler (or with the environment), not with CMake.

The linker is the same. Both the error message and verbose output of the compiler show /usr/bin/ld. That's why I posted: I don't know what the issue is. I guess an nvptx-none library isn't linked to, but why not, and now do I solve it?
